# jQuery UI Widget - Object has no method _super

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Calling base class methods doesn't seem to be working for me.
I have the following setup:

```
...
<div class='my'></div>
...
```

and Javascript

```
$.widget('tt.name1',{
    _create: function() {
        this.name = 'name'
        console.log('-->', this.name);
    }
});

$.widget('tt.name2',$.tt.name1, {
    _create: function() {
        this._super();
        /*$.tt.name1.prototype._create.call(this);*/
        this.name = 'name2'
        console.log('-->', this.name);
    }
});

$('.my').name1();
$('.my').name2();
```

which produces the following output and errors when invoking `this._super()`

> --> name
>   Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method '_super'

[these](http://bililite.com/blog/extending-jquery-ui-widgets/) [two](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-in-depth-review-of-jquerys-widget-factory/) links suggest that it should work

[try in action](http://jsfiddle.net/FvQUu/1/)

Comment: No. Both the pages you linked to use extra code in the WidgetFactory to make `_super` work.

Comment: @Bergi: Not the case. The examples use the widget factory which was introduced in 1.9. Shouldn't need anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These examples use the *widget factory* which was introduced in jQuery 1.9. Your example uses 1.8.9. If you upgrade to 1.9 your code will work fine.